# ¿Como descagar librerias de golang?

Tags: go

Hola tengo una pregunta muy grande y es que quiero descargar una libréria de go que necesito y el go get no me deja, alguien sabe alguna otra forma?????

por si acaso este es el error que me da, también estaría agradecido si me ayudan a arreglar el error:

```
package github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenés que setear la variable de entorno de Go `GOPATH`

[How to Write Go Code (with GOPATH)](https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code.html)

El GOPATH es el directorio o workspace donde tenes que crear tus proyectos de Go.

Otra solución, sería utilizar gomodules para gestionar la dependencia de paquetes.

[Using Go Modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules)

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes go 1.14:

```
mkdir miherramienta
cd miherramienta
go mod init github.com/minombre/miherramienta
```

Crea un archivo `main.go` con lo siguiente:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo"
)

func main() {
    n, err := discordgo.New()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("n: %v\n", n)
}
```

Y ya lo puedes correr:

```
$ go run main.go
n: &{{{0 0} 0 0 0 0}  false false 0 true { {linux DiscordGo v0.21.1   } true 250 <nil> {0 { 0 }  false} true 0xc0000163d8} true 0 1 true false false 3 0 false false map[] 0xc000154000 0xc00007ce10 DiscordBot (https://github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo, v0.21.1) 2020-06-30 07:17:06.192042 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0xc000070380 {{0 0} 0 0 0 0} map[] map[] <nil> <nil> 0xc0000163d0   {0 0}}
```